# How do I decrypt an AES key using C# Bouncy Castle that was encrypted using Libgcrypt raw flag

Tags: cryptography, aes, rsa, bouncycastle, libgcrypt

**Summary:**
I am attempting to decrypt (and eventually encrypt and return) files that are AES128 encrypted. The AES key is encrypted using libcrypt's RSA provider. When I attempt to decrypt the AESKey on Windows 7 using C# & BouncyCastle a "block truncated" error is thrown when I call "ProcessBlock". I have tried converting the data to BigEndian and I'll get a "Not a valid RSA exponent" when I try to create the RsaKeyParameters.

The encryption was done using libgcrypt 1.2x on a linux system. I think it's a padding issue since this snippet of code indicates that no padding is used.
`gcry_sexp_build(&PlainKeyExp, NULL, "(data (flags raw) (value %s))", AESKey );`

Unfortunately I cannot change the originating system. I'm including code samples & keys below to help. This has been driving me insane for the past 3 days. I've scoured the interwebz and have not found a solution.
Thank you in advance for your help.

**Originating code snippet**

```
static const char RSAPrivateKey[] =
"(private-key"
" (rsa"
"  (n #00e0ce96f90b6c9e02f3922beada93fe50a875eac6bcc18bb9a9cf2e84965caa"
"      2d1ff95a7f542465c6c0c19d276e4526ce048868a7a914fd343cc3a87dd74291"
"      ffc565506d5bbb25cbac6a0e2dd1f8bcaab0d4a29c2f37c950f363484bf269f7"
"      891440464baf79827e03a36e70b814938eebdc63e964247be75dc58b014b7ea251#)"
"  (e #010001#)"
"  (d #046129f2489d71579be0a75fe029bd6cdb574ebf57ea8a5b0fda942cab943b11"
"      7d7bb95e5d28875e0f9fc5fcc06a72f6d502464dabded78ef6b716177b83d5bd"
"      c543dc5d3fed932e59f5897e92e6f58a0f33424106a3b6fa2cbf877510e4ac21"
"      c3ee47851e97d12996222ac3566d4ccb0b83d164074abf7de655fc2446da1781#)"
"  (p #00e861b700e17e8afe6837e7512e35b6ca11d0ae47d8b85161c67baf64377213"
"      fe52d772f2035b3ca830af41d8a4120e1c1c70d12cc22f00d28d31dd48a8d424f1#)"
"  (q #00f7a7ca5367c661f8e62df34f0d05c10c88e5492348dd7bddc942c9a8f369f9"
"      35a07785d2db805215ed786e4285df1658eed3ce84f469b81b50d358407b4ad361#)"
"  (u #304559a9ead56d2309d203811a641bb1a09626bc8eb36fffa23c968ec5bd891e"
"      ebbafc73ae666e01ba7c8990bae06cc2bbe10b75e69fcacb353a6473079d8e9b#)))";

Error = gcry_sexp_sscan(&PublicKey, NULL, RSAPublicKey, strlen(RSAPublicKey));
if ( Error ) { goto Return; }

Error = gcry_sexp_sscan(&PrivateKey, NULL, RSAPrivateKey, strlen(RSAPrivateKey));
if ( Error ) { goto Return; }

Error = gcry_sexp_build(&PlainKeyExp, NULL, "(data (flags raw) (value %s))", AESKey );
gpg_strerror_r(Error, Output, 500);
if ( Error ) { goto Return; }

Error = gcry_pk_encrypt(&Encrypted, PlainKeyExp, PublicKey);
if ( Error ) { goto Return; }

if ( gcry_sexp_sprint(Encrypted, GCRYSEXP_FMT_CANON, Output, 500) <= 0 ) { Error = TRUE; goto Return; }
Encrypted = gcry_sexp_find_token(Encrypted, "a", 0);
if ( Encrypted == NULL ) { Error = TRUE; goto Return; }

if ( gcry_sexp_sprint(Encrypted, GCRYSEXP_FMT_ADVANCED, Output, 500) <= 0 ) { Error = TRUE; goto Return; }
if ( strtok(Output, "#") != NULL ) {
    Output2 = strtok(NULL, "#");
    if ( Output2 != NULL ) { sprintf(EncryptedKey,"%s", Output2); }
    else { Error = TRUE; }
} else { Error = TRUE; }
```

**Decoding code snippet**

```
var modulus ="00e0ce96f90b6c9e02f3922beada93fe50a875eac6bcc18bb9a9cf2e84965caa2d1ff95a7f542465c6c0c19d276e4526ce048868a7a914fd343cc3a87dd74291ffc565506d5bbb25cbac6a0e2dd1f8bcaab0d4a29c2f37c950f363484bf269f7891440464baf79827e03a36e70b814938eebdc63e964247be75dc58b014b7ea251";

var privateExponent ="046129f2489d71579be0a75fe029bd6cdb574ebf57ea8a5b0fda942cab943b117d7bb95e5d28875e0f9fc5fcc06a72f6d502464dabded78ef6b716177b83d5bdc543dc5d3fed932e59f5897e92e6f58a0f33424106a3b6fa2cbf877510e4ac21c3ee47851e97d12996222ac3566d4ccb0b83d164074abf7de655fc2446da1781";

var encryptedAesKey ="77FD84196959DDE3C367952B3C25B34582B489A705FB3C61D69D04DDA16B011F6358F32834DD76BF81A1DF28106F377FF1125F91CA39BB92D293B8F5134C15C17DE1157390723301A01B938489E04DA1D8D4A70511F0FF2508984710CEB3F18D4BA929C18487A0977011BDE169DBBF3047646FBFBC50ED5A02FC40E53E59B8CD";

try
{
  // Convert to biginteger
  var bcMod = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(Hex.Decode(modulus));
  var bcPrivateExponent = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(Hex.Decode(privateExponent));
  byte[] decodedAesKey = Hex.Decode(encryptedAesKey);

  // Init bouncyCastle
  var privParameters = new RsaKeyParameters(true, bcMod, bcPrivateExponent);
  var eng = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
  eng.Init(false, privParameters);

  var ret = eng.ProcessBlock(decodedAesKey, 0, 128);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simply to remove the `new Pkcs1Encoding()` constructor call and directly use `RsaEngine`. If there is no padding, then there is no need to remove or validate it.

Note that padding is a requirement to create a secure RSA based ciphertext. So this is OK to overcome compatibility issues, but the system should be replaced right away.

Comment: Also note that PKCS#1v1.5 padding is not secure – you should use OAEP.

Comment: @ntoskrnl Yep, PKCS#1 1.5 is not *as* secure as OAEP padding. Compared to *no padding* PKSC#1 v1.5 padding is however very secure :)

Comment: Thank you @owlstead! The answer was right there under my nose! I agree and understand that this is 'less than optimal' but it is what it is.

Comment: Also to note.. sometimes the encrypted AESKey has leading zeros which need to be removed before decrypting.

Comment: In principle RSA encryption delivers a number as ciphertext. Normally this is encoded as a byte array with the same length as the key (the answer of course always fits inside the modulus). For a *padded* encryption method this means that the answer is always *about* the size of the modulus.  The chances of it being one byte smaller is about 1 over 192, the chances of it being two bytes smaller is about 1 over 192 times 256. Again for decryption, the ciphertext is treated as a number. Leading zero's should not be a problem. If you have got over two/three leading zero's then you are in trouble.